# ToolBox missing for Xamarin Android Project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin in VS 2015. I am not able to see the design view of the axml file. The controls in the toolbox are missing too.

Are there any settings I need to look at? I have tried to do a reset all settings from the Tools - Import And Export Settings option.

How do I get the toolbox to work?[image: Toolbox Missing]